# JOIN on Sub-query with Virtual Keys Changes SUM on Main Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I am aggregating daily data to monthly from several sources. The original query goes like this:

```
SELECT
  D.MonthDate
  ,S.StoreName
  ,ISNULL(SUM(P.ProductSales),0) Sales
  ,ISNULL(SUM(A.AccessorySales),0) Accessories
FROM StoreDirectory S
JOIN DateDimension D
  ON DayDate >= '2014-01-01'
  AND DayDate <= '2014-12-31'
LEFT JOIN ProductData P
  ON P.StoreName = S.StoreName
  AND P.ActivityDate = D.DayDate
LEFT JOIN AccessoryData A
  ON A.StoreName = S.StoreName
  AND A.ActivityDate = D.DayDate
GROUP BY
  D.MonthDate
  ,S.StoreName
```

The idea is to build a table with a value for each store for each day of the year. (The DateDimension table has a row for every day with other convenient reference info like the last day of the month in MonthDate) Then, if there is activity information in P and D, join it to the row. Then, the GROUP BY and SUMs aggregate this data to the month.

This works.

I need to scale ProductSales by a factor, so I have build a sub-query that contains a unique row for each MonthDate with the scaling factor. Literally just two columns, like this (twelve rows, one for each month-end date):

```
MonthDate     Factor
---------     ------
2014-01-31    1.2
2014-02-28    0.8
etc...
```

MonthDate is a virtual primary key - there is only one row for each MonthDate.

I added a line to JOIN this subquery to the above table, included the Factor in the SELECT statement, and added it to the the grouped column list:

```
SELECT
  D.MonthDate
  ,S.StoreName
  ,F.Factor --Added this factor field
  ,ISNULL(SUM(P.ProductSales),0) Sales
  ,ISNULL(SUM(A.AccessorySales),0) Accessories
FROM StoreDirectory S
JOIN DateDimension D
  ON DayDate >= '2014-01-01'
  AND DayDate <= '2014-12-31'

--Updated to more closely resemble the actual sub-query
JOIN (
  SELECT
    FT.MonthDate
    ,SUM(FT.Factor)
  FROM FactorTable FT
  JOIN DateDimension D
    ON FT.DailyContribution = D.DayDate
  GROUP BY
    MonthDate) F
  ON F.MonthDate = D.MonthDate

LEFT JOIN ProductData P
  ON P.StoreName = S.StoreName
  AND P.ActivityDate = D.DayDate
LEFT JOIN AccessoryData A
  ON A.StoreName = S.StoreName
  AND A.ActivityDate = D.DayDate
GROUP BY
  D.MonthDate
  ,S.StoreName
  ,F.Factor --Added Factor to the GROUP BY
```

I assumed this would simply add the appropriate factor as a column to the existing SUMs. It does not. It instead calculates much larger SUMs than the original query.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix it and maintain the existing aggregations?

I need the Factor to (optionally) adjust sales numbers in another context...

Many thanks for the help - let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Can you include your actual subquery, obviously what you have will not run:  `SELECT MonthDate, Factor FROM Table WHERE Conditions GROUP BY MonthDate` - There is something wrong in whatever you're doing for real.

Comment: It's too ugly for context, but the output (when run as an independent SELECT query) is exactly those two columns. Would it matter? I can verify the output and there is only one row per MonthDate. What are you thinking?

Comment: To clarify - this is an abstracted example of the problem I'm facing to simplify the investigation. That's why it's difficult to copy/paste. In actuality, there are two unique keys in the sub-query, but I am joining on both of them, so there should be only one match to any primary row.

Comment: There is likely an issue with your sub-query.  As @DanielGimenez mentioned, it is tough to give an actual answer without the details of the actual question.  The query you have listed above will not compile b/c the Factor column in the subquery `F` is not in an aggregate function or group by clause.

Comment: When you say "there are two unique keys in the sub-query", does that mean there are 2 columns that make up a single unique key in the sub-query? And if so, are those the **only** columns that are in the `group by` of your subquery?

Comment: Added more detail to make the sub-query more closely resemble the structure of the real one. It compiles. It produces the expected output...

Comment: @BateTech - There are two columns and yes, the two of them are the only items in the GROUP BY). Think of it like MonthEnd and Region, e.g. 2014-04-30 North or 2014-12-31 South, etc. I also JOIN exclusively on those fields as displayed in the SELECT with an AND operator. Should just have a single match for each row, with no rows missing a match (no possible NULL results or other exclusions).

Comment: I can't think of anything that would produce the results you mentioned given this query.  At first I was thinking an implicit conversion between data types of `F.MonthDate` and `D.MonthDate` could cause an issue if `F.MonthDate` was `datetime` and `D.MonthDate` is `date`... but in that case I think `D.MonthDate` would be implicitly converted to `datetime` to avoid a narrowing conversion, which would not cause your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, folks!

Discovered my error:

The `AccessoryData` table had multiple rows for each `DayDate` which were duplicating rows from the rest of the data. Check your sources, folks!